# How to code so date expires by adding month(s)?

Tags: javascript

Below, I'm showing a line which ends undefined and not adding numbers 3, 6 or 12. Using this value, as radio button, to give integer number in the code.

`let addMonth = months[date.getMonth() + input];`

Mainly the `input` variable is not working in the code below.

```js
    let inputThree = document.getElementById("input_3");
    let inputSix = document.getElementById("input_6");
    let inputTwelve = document.getElementById("input_12");

    var input = "";

    if (inputThree.checked) {
        input = inputThree.value;
    } else if (inputSix.checked) {
        input = inputSix.value;
    }  else if (inputTwelve.checked) {
        input = inputTwelve.value;
    }

    let addMonth = months[date.getMonth() + input];

    document.getElementById('expiries').innerHTML = day + "<sup>"+th+"</sup>"+"&nbsp"+ addMonth +"&nbsp"+ year;

}
```

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? It's not that clear, unfortunately.

Comment: Be sure to provide a [mre]. You might want something like `addMonth = months[(date.getMonth() + Number(input.value)) % 12]`

Comment: I want to get an expiration date after Radio button value which in this case is "1" so the month should show November. 
<input class="radio" type="radio" id="input_3" name="input" value="1">
this was my html code.